# When are customer journey maps useful?

Tags: user-journey

How do I find data to build customer journey maps?

I ran some surveys but I don't think that survey answers are useful enough to build a customer journey map. I don't have enough emotional data, but I don't know how to get them.

Maybe through interviews? And in this case, the interview have to be made before the dev of the website or service, or after that this is already developed?

I'm asking this question because, before start working on my project I ran some survey to get insights from users, to shape the experience. But I noticed that data I got aren't enough useful to know their emotion during the use of the site.

Lastly: at what stage in a project would it be the right time to develop a customer journey map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customer journey maps are frequently used in the **designing of the experience.**

Once you have a product idea, **list functionality and features you'd like to include**. Then, **interview potential users/customers.** This is when you discover their **needs and emotions.** At his point, you have not yet built your product, so you don't know how they feel as they are using it (it doesn't exist). However, you do know how they feel in general when they are in need of completing the task, which will be accomplished in your product.

For example, if the task is to share a link with a friend, we can identify the common emotions and problems users face with this task:

- Eager to share quickly
- Desire to share across platforms (some friends use WhatsApp while others use Google Hangouts or Facebook)
- Frustration of accessibility on some devices (it's difficult to select, copy, and paste on small phones)

Think without limitations, the **ideal way** for the user to complete the task. This is the user journey.

Once you identify the user's needs and wants, you can now prioritize your list of **functionality and features**.

Then, after you achieve prioritization, you begin to **frame the designs**.

Sometimes, if the product is already built, we may observe users using the product. Gather their emotions, needs, and wants through research.

Then, we could step back and develop the ideal experience/user journey once again, and contrast the ideal to the existing experience.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest producing a Customer Experience Map (CEM) based on user needs to map the transitions in the customer journey. Then create content/offers/interactions to track movement along the journey to track interest and engagement.

I have created some content covers/title and showed them to user and ask them if they would read or share this. I then ask them about their affinity to the product or service to determine their state of mind in the CEM.

This will align your content offers with the state in your digital marketing system.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the type of questions you would ask to get information about user's emotions (e.g. what works well? what frustrates you?) in response to the question about not being able to gather this information from the users? Also, the second part of the question about when the best time to do this research, do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score -1):

Here are some of the ways the Customer Journey Map can help:

1) Alignment across the board

2) Deeper Customer Insights

3) Opportunity to increase top-line growth

4) Create a unified experience across multiple services and products

More details can be found at [What is a Customer Journey Map and why is it important?](https://www.ideatheorem.com/insights/what-is-customer-journey-map-why-is-it-important/)

Comment: In your answer, try to address the specific questions that are being asked, specifically how to gather emotional data from the users and the stage of the project where the journey map should be developed (based on your experience or other references). If you can summarize key points from the reference that would also improve the quality of the answer.